# Find the number of integral values of $x$ for which the expression has an integer value for every positive integer $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the number of integral values of $x$ for which the expression
$ \frac {4^n + 15n - 1}{x} $
has an integer value for every positive integer $n$.

I tried $n = 1$ but I don't really know what to do.

Comment: "Integral values of x". What is "integral value"?

Comment: integers values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well obviously $x=1$ will work because $1$ divides all integers. One thing you could do is start plugging in values of $n$ and see what you get. The first few are $18,45,108...$. What divides all of them? Well, their gcd is $9$. So now we want to test our conjecture that $9|4^n+15n-1$ for all $n$.

This is probably easiest to prove by induction on $n$.

Base case: $n=1$
$$4^1+15-1=18=2 \times 9$$
Assume $4^k+15k-1 = 9A$ for some integer $A$.

Inductive step: $n=k+1$
$$4^{k+1}+15(k+1)-1=4(4^k)+15k+14$$
$$4^{k+1}+15(k+1)-1=4(4^k)+60k-4-45k+18$$
$$4^{k+1}+15(k+1)-1=4(4^k+15k-1)-45k+18=4(9A)-9(5k)+9(2)$$
$$4^{k+1}+15(k+1)-1=9(4A-5k+2)$$
So $9|4^n+15n-1$ by induction.

Comment: I don't really understand how the conjecture helps us find all x.

Comment: @132479 $x$ needs to divide all the numbers in the sequence. There are only a small number of possible candidates, which are the numbers $x$ that divide the first three numbers in the sequence. If you can show that all these work, you've found all the possibilities.

Comment: @healynr the third term should be $108$, not $105$.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Well that throws a wrench into my answer, doesn't it? Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

By Induction, 4n+15n−1≡0

So 4n≡1−15n and thus

4n+1+15(n+1)−1=4⋅4n+15n+14≡4⋅(1−15n)+15n+14=18−45n≡0

since both 18 and 45 are divisible by 9.

Also gcd(first 3 terms)=9 ,so 9 is the largest value of x

Also it follows that 1,3,9 are the possible values for x.

Therefore the answer is 3.

Comment: The solution by healynr is slightly incorrect

Comment: the 3rd term is 108 not 105

Comment: For more challenging questions such as this I recommend W. Sierpinski's 250 problems in elementary number theory.

Comment: Please format your posts using mathjax.